# React-redux: как лучше организовать библиотеку компонентов?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Хочу сделать библиотеку компонентов, чтобы можно было использовать в разных приложениях. Естественно, один компонент из библиотеки может использовать другой компонент, допустим начальный рендеринг такой:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <AppMain>
    <Library_LoginForm />
  </AppMain>
</Provider>
```

Library_LoginForm - компонент из библиотеки. Он в свою очередь использует два компонента текстового ввода, в результате render получается таким:

```
class Library_LoginForm {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Library_TextInput caption="Логин" />
        <Library_TextInput caption="Пароль" hidden="true" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Компоненты Library_LoginForm, Library_TextInput не знают о хранилище конкретного приложения. Они ожидают, что в их props окажется необходимая им информация. Она там окажется в результате срабатывания функций вида mapToProps при использовании @connect из react-redux.
Но ведь один библиотечный компонент тогда должен в случае нужды в другом библиотечном компоненте использовать его "@connect"-версию. А откуда он его возьмет?

Конечно, можно делать @connect только компонентам "верхнего уровня", а они пусть сами пробрасывают props'ы дочерним, но может есть красивое решение как "законнектить" конкретный библиотечный компонент на конкретное хранилище приложения?

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно, в чём проблема в вашем конкретном примере. Компонент LoginForm должен получить все пропсы, которые он передаст дочерним компонентам. Можете описать интерфейс компонента TextInput и импортировать его в интерфейс LoginForm, это уменьшит количество писанины.

```
// TextInput.tsx
type TextInputProps = {
    hidden?: boolean;
    value?: string;
    error?: boolean;
    label?: string;
    onClick?: (e: React.SyntheticEvent<any>) => any;
};

// LoginForm.tsx
type LoginFormProps = {
    loginInput: TextInputProps;
    passwordInput: TextInputProps;
}

const Library_LoginForm: React.SFC<LoginFormProps> = props => (
    <div>
        <Library_TextInput {...props.loginInput} />
        <Library_TextInput {...props.passwordInput} />
      </div>
);
```

Однако, если разговор идёт о формах, то не лучше ли будет использовать redux-form или аналог.

Comment: Пример же тестовый. Да, можно сделать connect для LoginForm, а он уже передаст нужные props "ниже". Но, допустим, компонентам ниже нужны какие-то сложные данные из хранилища, логично их тоже приконнектить к хранилищу с помощью connect. Но как тогда компонент верхнего уровня узнает "connect-версию" компонента?

Comment: обычный подход состоит в разделении компонентов на компоненты и контейнры, где первый тупые и просто рисуют интерфейс, а последний знают про стор, рутер и подобные вещи. компоненты легко вынести в отдельную библиотеку, контейнеры не получится, так как они составляют само приложение

Comment: А если одному компоненту нужно в своей работе использовать другой компонент. Он ведь не может использовать контейнер, так как ничего о нем не знает. Но и компонент без контейнера не обладает нужными данными.
В этом и вопрос

Comment: правильно, конечно, поэтому я и привёл пример выше как пропсы передаются сквозь компоненты, собственно не понянто в чём проблема :)